# How to do backward subset selection on a random forest model for classification?

Tags: r, classification, caret

I'd like to identify the most predictive features for my classification model. I'm using this [data](https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/).

Here is a sample.

[image]

This is my code. I'd like to use the predictors to predict loan status.

```
library(caret)

folds <- 10
cvIndex <- createFolds(factor(Vc$Loan_Status), folds, returnTrain = T)
tc <- trainControl(index = cvIndex,
                   method = 'cv', 
                   number = folds)


preProcValues <- preProcess(Vc, method = c("center","scale"))
train_processed <- predict(preProcValues, Vc)
train_processed$Loan_Status <- ifelse(train_processed$Loan_Status==FALSE,0,1)

index <- createDataPartition(train_processed$quoteCreated, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
trainSet <- train_processed[ index,]
testSet <- train_processed[-index,]

control <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,
                      method = "repeatedcv",
                      repeats = 3,
                      verbose = FALSE)

outcomeName<-'Loan_Status'
predictors<-names(trainSet)[!(names(trainSet) %in% outcomeName | names(trainSet) == "Loan_ID")]
Quote_Pred_Profile <- rfe(trainSet[,predictors], trainSet[,outcomeName],
                          metric = "Accuracy",
                          maximizize = TRUE,
                         rfeControl = control)
plot(Quote_Pred_Profile)
```

I get the warning message:

> In randomForest.default(x, y, importance = TRUE, ...) :   The response
>   has five or fewer unique values.  Are you sure you want to do
>   regression?

Why is it serving this error? Is this the right way to do subset selection to prep for classification?

Also, when I run `plot(Quote_Pred_Profile)`, it serves a plot with RMSE on the y-axis.

Comment: Sorry the data is an image. If anyone has tips on how to copy and paste from excel, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out. It was a data-type issue. I coded my response variable as 0-1, under the impression that was necessary for caret. I just gave it another try with this code.

```
Quote_Pred_Profile <- rfe(trainSet[,predictors], as.factor(trainSet[,outcomeName]),
                          metric = "Accuracy",
                          maximizize = TRUE,
                         rfeControl = control)
```

And it is working just I expected, along with a chart that shows the accuracy for each possible number of variables.